# Android Studio creating board programmatically

Tags: java, android, layout

I am currently trying to create my first board Android game and struggling with my layout. My code only creates one row of the board. I have read almost every post but could not find anything useful.

```
public class Nonogram extends AppCompatActivity {

private Field field = new Field(10,10,75);

private ImageView[][] board = new ImageView[field.getRowCount()][field.getColumnCount()];

Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nonogram);
    context = this;
    draw();
}

private void draw(){

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.nonogram);

    for(int row = 0; row < field.getRowCount(); row ++) {

        LinearLayout rowl = new LinearLayout(context);

        for (int column = 0; column < field.getColumnCount(); column++) {

            board[row][column] = new ImageView(context);

            if (field.getUserTiles()[row][column].getState() == TileState.FILLED) {
                board[row][column].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filled);

            } else if (field.getUserTiles()[row][column].getState() == TileState.EMPTY) {
                board[row][column].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty);

            } else {
                board[row][column].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marked);
            }

            rowl.addView(board[row][column]);
        }
        relativeLayout.addView(rowl);
    }
}
```

The XML is just the Relative Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/nonogram"
android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
tools:context="pocketfun.org.pocketfun.nonogram.Nonogram">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LinearLayout as root instead (don't forget the android:orientation="vertical"):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/nonogram"
android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
tools:context="pocketfun.org.pocketfun.nonogram.Nonogram">

</LinearLayout>
```

And adjust your code:

```
LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nonogram);

for(int row = 0; row < field.getRowCount(); row ++) {
    [...]
    rootLayout.addView(row1);
}
```

Comment: My apologies, forgot.